# modifying CSS for a specific class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have CSS:

```
div.box { color:black; }
div.box.open { background:red; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">text...</div>
```

How to change CSS definition in JQuery for "div.box.open" ?
I don't want to change CSS for the element but the class definitions
eg.

```
div.box.open { background:red; }  ---> div.box.open { background:orange; }
```

How to do it?

using:

```
$("div.box.open").css("background", "orange")
```

changes the style of the element but not the definition.
I need to change the definition.

Comment: Out of interest – why do you want to change the actual CSS definition itself (just to give a bit more context to help). Mainly as actually altering a stylesheet using jQuery is fairly challenging.

Comment: While there are some aus to do that in standard DOM, jQuery has no helper features for it.

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y question. As mentioned above, your attempted solution of on-the-fly updating of CSS rules is not straightforward, and very far from ideal. I would suggest that instead you add another class to the element which sets the rules you require, overriding those already set if necessary.

Comment: Or add a class to the body and css rules accordingly, eg `.message { color:green } body.error .message { color:red; }`